# Python Tic-Tac-Toe Spot Already Occupied

Tags: python

I'm working on making Tic-Tac-Toe in Python between 2 human players, and I'm having issues getting my code to realize that a spot is already occupied.

I made 2 lists:

```
board = [1, 2, 3,
         4, 5, 6,
         7, 8, 9]
```

```
PLAYER_NAMES = ["Nobody", "X", "O"]
```

And now I'm working on defining a function that allows players to make moves, but for the life of me I can't get it to reject a spot if it has already been occupied

```
    if next_player(player) == 2:
        print("Current Player: X")
    else:
        print("Current Player: O")
    response = input("Enter a number between 1 and 9: ")
    if response.isnumeric():
        input_response = int(response)
        if input_response == 0 or input_response > 9:
            print("That number is not valid")
        elif 1 <= input_response <= 9:
            for i in range(len(board)):
                if input_response == int(i + 1):
                    board[i] = player
    if not response.isnumeric():
        print("Please Enter a Valid Input!")
        pass
```

So far I'm having it so that a players input needs to equal the index position of the number in the grid (so 1 would be 0 + 1, as it is index position 0 obviously) for it to replace it. It will then be switched to X or O depending on which player does the inputting. This is working fine.

How can I get it to reject inputs if that spot is already occupied? I've tried setting it so that if the list element is not numeric then it will reject it, but it hasn't been working for me.

Comment: Seems to me that the values `1..9` in `board` are not doing anything useful.  Might be easier to use something like `None` as a sentinel.

Comment: I don't see that code you mentioned where you check the current board. If you could not make it work, it must have an error somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if the value of board[i] is not X or O (i.e. not occupied)

```
if board[i] == "Nobody":
    board[i] = player
else:
    print("Spot already occupied!")
```

Though, I would suggest you to use a two dimensional array instead of a single dimension array for representing the grid. Here are some links that may help you

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_2darray.htm

https://snakify.org/en/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/

Comment: So this code is causing every input to read that the spot is already occupied

Comment: My code or your code? Your code simply does not check if a player already marked the spot. If you insert my code in your code, then it will check if the spot is already marked or not

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could make list by having tuple in it with digit and Boolean value. Let me explain

```
Board= [(1,False),(2,False),(3,False).. so on  ]

if not board[I][1] :
    board[I] = Player
    board[I][1] = True
```

I think this should work